# session data transfer between two different host

Tags: php

i have two websites hosted on different host,
xyz.net63.net & abc.comli.com
i want to transfer data fetched from db and stored in session at php page of xyz.net63.net 
to php page of abc.comli.com

php page to send data (at xyz.net63.net)

```
<?php session_start();                 
    $_SESSION['customer_name'] = "test"; //data to pass
    $link = "http://abc.comli.com"; //data pass to

    //link for call update page
    echo "<br/><a href=\"$link/create_db.php\">Click here</a> to update.
 ?>
```

php page to recieve data (at abc.comli.com)

```
<?php session_start();               
    $data = $_SESSION['customer_name']; //DATA APPEARS NOTHING HERE 
 ?>
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: Such thing you try to do with sessions is impossible. But you can connect from second host to first host database.

Comment: is there any other way of passing secure data between two websites. i am actually sending public-private key to user, so public key encryption is not a chance

Comment: you could use a databaseconnector that supports ssl and connect from site A to database A write some data and then connect from site B to database A and retreive this exact data. that would be a kind of secure way as long as database A is accessible from the outside

Comment: ok i will try this and let you know, but wont it make database A unsecure as at heacy traffic multiple user registration data will be saved and will be accessible to one another

Comment: i hv solved the problem. my one page is setting session data into post and send it as autosubmitted post variables, which is then received by another server page. but SECURITY??? is a problem

Comment: I am now sending data by post with session key to encrypt data, and public key to encrypt session key and hence sending encrypted data and encrypted session key via post. it takes time to send comparing to GET and SESSION but secure. make sure to make time limit 0 and all form text box hidden